# Delete posts of deleted user wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I am using buddypress with `wordpress`.I accidentally deleted a user directly in data base table `wp_users`. Therefore just the user only deleted but the posts posted by him remains in the site. How to `delete all the posts` related to that deleted user. Is there any way?

Comment: Give the table schema of `wp_users` and `posts`

Answer (score 1):

Do it carefully this is the Query to detect all the posts from the deleted user to confirm that, the select query show you the post of the user that are not found in `wp_users` table.

```
SELECT *
    FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_author` NOT
    IN (
        SELECT id
           FROM `wp_users`
       )
```

And this is hows you run the delete query.

```
DELETE
    FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_author` NOT
    IN (
        SELECT id
           FROM `wp_users`
       )
```

#### Run this query in your database.